# Android: Identical lines of code not working in seperate methods

Tags: java, android, exception, reference

If I happen to use a few lines of code in the same method as the construction of the called variables, it works, but if I would create another method that would just do **the same operation, copy-pasted** and then just call the other method inside it, it wouldn't work.

```
    private void initElements(){

    TextView ageValue[] =
            {
                    (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age1Value),
                    (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age2Value),
                    (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age3Value)
            };

    TextView ageText[] =
            {
                    (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age1Text),
                    (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age2Text),
                    (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age3Text)
            };

            for(int i = 0; i<=2;i++){


        intValues[i] = a.getHours((i));
        stringValues[i] = String.valueOf(intValues[i]);
        ageValue[i].setText(stringValues[i]);

    }

    //updateValues();

}

private void updateValues(){


                for(int i = 0; i<=2;i++){


        intValues[i] = a.getHours((i));
        stringValues[i] = String.valueOf(intValues[i]);
        ageValue[i].setText(stringValues[i]);

    }



    }
```

If I would uncomment the updateValues() function, the program wouldn't run, even though the same code would be executed in the function before. Moreover, debugging would lead after this statement:

```
        ageValue[i].setText(stringValues[i]);
```

to this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuFbd.png)

I've tried rebuilding and cleaning the program and reinstalling it. I tried it on a virtual device and my real smartphone. Same error over and over. (Moreover, it sometimes says that "Source code does not match the bytecode" when I hover on the error in the picture, but sometimes it also doesn't." Also tried the "this." keyword everywhere, but no success.

I am just baffled how this could happen. Maybe the method does not get some sort of right memory reference because it is not directly next to the declaration but I mean the two statements before the "error statement" work perfectly fine, despite them having the same nature. It would be great if you could like enlighten me why this does not work, thanks!

```
    TextView ageValue[] = new TextView[3];
TextView ageText[] = new TextView[3];

int intValues[] = new int[3];
String stringValues[] = new String[3];

CalculateDates a = new CalculateDates();
```

This is the declaration of the used variables. (That's in the beginning of the class)

Comment: The `ageValue` in `updateValues()` is not the same `ageValue` you've declared and initialized in `initElements()`. `TextView ageValue[]` declares a new, different variable with the same name that's local to `initElements()`.

Comment: @MikeM. But the declaration itself isn't in the initElements() function. The declaration (see my edit) is in the beginning of the class or am I getting something wrong? Would using the "this." keyword help?

Comment: Yes, it is. `TextView ageValue[]` is a declaration. It's a different, separate declaration than the class field.

Comment: @MikeM. So I need to use the "this." keyword to specifically refer to the ageValue[] created in this instance?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just don't declare another `ageValue` there. Just assign it, or its items. For example, to assign the items individually: `ageValue[0] = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.age1Value); ...`. Alternatively, to assign the whole array: `ageValue = new TextView[] { (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.age1Value), ... };`.

Comment: @MikeM. Didn't even occur to me lol. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the global ageValue[] and ageText[]  for that class.

```
private void initElements(){

    ageValue[0] =(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age1Value);
    ageValue[1] =(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age2Value);
    ageValue[2] =(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age3Value);


   ageText[0] = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age1Text);
   ageText[1] = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age2Text);
   ageText[2] = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.age3Text);



        for(int i = 0; i<=2;i++){


    intValues[i] = a.getHours((i));
    stringValues[i] = String.valueOf(intValues[i]);
    ageValue[i].setText(stringValues[i]);

}
```

Do not declare the TextViews inside the method also.

You were creating different instances of those textViews in initElements() method and the global TextViews were still null

Comment: > Do not declare the TextViews inside the method also.| That was the main problem here. But yeah, should use globals for specific instances

Comment: You were creating different instances of those textViews in initElements() method and the global TextViews were still null. If this worked don't forget to accept it.

Comment: "You were creating different instances of those textViews in initElements() method and the global TextViews were still null" Add this to your post and then I will accept it. It describes the problem better than the original first line.

Comment: I did mention this in my answer.